# web shop (shopping cart) on google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine

there are currently no off-the-shelf shopping carts for use on Google App Engine

is the only solution on GAE at the moment to bespoke your own?

what has other people done in terms of a shopping facility on GAE?

Comment: just wondering, why choosing GAE for a shopping cart?

Answer (score 1):

PayPal is offering a new open source toolkit for Google App Engine that lets you integrate Java apps running on App Engine with the new PayPal Adaptive Payments API. The Adaptive Payments API lets developers embed payments into their apps, services, and platforms.

Here is a link to the google appengine blog: [paypal-introduces-paypal-x-platform](http://googleappengine.blogspot.com/2010/06/paypal-introduces-paypal-x-platform.html)

There will be a Python version of the toolkit coming out soon, PayPal says.

Comment: Looks like Paymate could be easily integrated too, they have a free shopping cart: http://www.paymate.com/cms/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=184&Itemid=252